# How to do DFT of this signal

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

I am trying to get $X[k]$ when $x[n]$ is equal to

$$x[n] = \cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{4}n-\tfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

I'm using this equation:

$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}{N}kn}$$

but I'm really getting stuck.
So far I have done Euler on the cosine and I am now trying to multiply the two exponents I get from this with the exponent on the right hand side of the equation that I have included above but I cannot get it into any form that I can convert using the DFT.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 3):

A large share of such questions are addressed via known sum of series. With trigonometrics arguments like $\cos(\alpha n+\beta)$, one solution is to use Euler/De Moivre formulae:

$$\cos(\alpha n+\beta) = \frac{e^{j(\alpha n+\beta)}+e^{-j(\alpha n+\beta)}}{2}$$

and recognize, under the Fourier sum, two geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{e^{j(\alpha n+\beta)}+e^{-j(\alpha n+\beta)}}{2}e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$$
with terms like :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left( e^{j(\pm\alpha -j2\pi k/N)}\right)^n$$
whose sum is well-known. For a given  $k$, you have:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{\pm j(\alpha n+\beta)}e^{-j2\pi kn/N} &= & e^{\pm j\beta}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{\pm j\alpha n-j2\pi kn/N}\\
&= & e^{\pm j\beta}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j(\pm \alpha -2\pi k/N)n}\\
&= & e^{\pm j\beta}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(e^{j(\pm \alpha -2\pi k/N)}\right)^n\\
\end{align}
$$
and then, noting

$$ \rho = e^{j(\pm \alpha -2\pi k/N)}$$
you can get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\rho^n =\begin{cases}N \textrm{ when } \rho=1, \\\frac{1-\rho^N}{1-\rho} \textrm{ when } \rho\neq 1.\end{cases} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you be able to tell me how you got from the second to the third equation?

Comment: I have combined the above with the $\pm$ sign

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the DFT values will depend on whether $N$ is a multiple of 8.  If it is, you will have a whole number of cycles and all the DFT values will be zero except at $N/4$ and $3N/4$.  [Correction: $N/8$ and $7N/8$]

You can find the math for the exact calculation in my blog article [DFT Bin Value Formulas for Pure Real Tones](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php).  I use slightly different terminology and a $1/N$ normalized DFT, but you should be able to follow along.

In your case $ \alpha = \pi / 4 $ and $ \phi = -\pi / 4 $.  You can jump to equations (23)-(25) if $N$ is not a multiple of 8, otherwise use equation (19).

Yes, this approach uses Euler's equation and the geometric summation formula so you were on the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response! How come N should be a multiple of 8 for this to be true? Did you deduce this from something in my question or is it always the case?

Comment: @CoderEH, It is because $ \pi / 4 $ is one eighth the way around the unit circle.  Thus, your signal is periodic at 8 samples.  A DFT of a pure tone with a whole number of cycles in the sample frame is qualitatively different than a fractional number of cycles.  It is a special case.

Comment: Thanks, so if I had $\pi / 5$ then I would be looking to see if N=10?

Comment: @CoderEH, Correct, or a multiple of 10.  The key is if there are a whole number of cycles in the sample frame.